# Confirming a user is the Wikipedia user they say they are?

Tags: identity, wikipedia

If a user on my site said they were the Wikipedia user "example" what would be the best way of confirming they are indeed that Wikipedia user & not an imposter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask them to put something on their user page, then check the history to see whether it was really them who put it there.

Comment: You know when you just can't think of the most obvious thing.  I kept thinking, but anyone can add something to their userpage! Doh!  Thanks, how stupid can I get!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia also supports [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:OAuth), so you should be able to ask them to authenticate with OAuth to prove that they are who they say they are.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check the History tab to double check they were really the one making the comment